# How to return an Array of Objects from a function

Tags: c++

This simple object return works fine.

```
Bubbles& Foo() {
  static Bubbles foo(10);
  foo.print();
  return foo;
}

int main() {

  Bubbles *bar;
  bar = &Foo();

  bar->print();

  printf("Program Ends");
  return 0;
}
```

Now I need to know how to return an Array of Objects!
I have 0 idea on how I should declare it 
 All I know is:

```
Bubbles& createBubbles() {
 static Bubbles *BubblesArray[arrayNumber];
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber; i++) {
    BubblesArray[i] = new Bubbles(i);
    BubblesArray[i]->print();

  }

  return BubblesArray;
}
```

seems to create an array of Objects the way I need. 
 So how can I return this array so I can use it outside the function?

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` and this becomes trivial. Otherwise it's not happening unless you pass the array as an output parameter.

Comment: `BubblesArray` is a pointer to the start of an array. Hence you want the return type to be `Bubbles*` i.e. `Bubbles* createBubbles()`, then the return statement makes sense. Note that you using a static variable won't play nice with multi-threading and there's a lot of memory leak in the code. Consider using std:: functions and classes such as std::vector and std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr.

Comment: Why is the variable `static`? This is, except in narrow circumstances, a bad design. If you added an explanation of why you think that is necessary, then we could probably suggest a better approach.

Comment: ok so I guess the best approach is std:: functions.

I will try std::vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type expects only 1 `Bubbles` object. If you want to return an array, you have to change the function return type. I would strongly recommend not playing with raw array and stick with the std library. Using C++11 (DISCLAIMER: CODE UNTESTED) will look something along the line of:

```
std::vector<Bubbles> createBubbles(const int& arrayNumber) {
 std::vector<Bubbles> bubblesVector;
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber; i++) {
    bubblesVector.push_back(Bubbles(i));
    bubblesVector[i].print();    
  }    
  return bubblesVector;
}
```

Note that this assume your `Bubbles` object has appropriate default/copy/move constructor, destructor, assignment operator...

Simple return type `std::vector<Bubbles>` can take advantage of [copy-elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which is extremely efficient.

Comment: Since the OP has no need for resizing the array, I think `std::array<Bubbles, arrayNumber>` would be better here.

Comment: Bubbles tend to pop. I'd suggest a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same behavior as in your first example. You just have to specify the type correctly:

```
using BubblesArrayType = Bubbles*[arrayNumber];

BubblesArrayType& createBubbles() {
  static BubblesArrayType BubblesArray;
  //...
  return BubblesArray;
}
```

or you can let type deduction figure the type out for you:

```
auto& createBubbles() {
  static Bubbles *BubblesArray[arrayNumber];
  //...
  return BubblesArray;
}
```

But as mentioned in comments and other answers, this is unlikely to be a good design and style. Without further information it is not really clear though, why you are using `static` and return-by-reference in the first place.

Comment: Also possible without the typedef, though even uglier:
`Bubbles* (&createBubbles())[arrayNumber] { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @N.Shead I hope I will never see that in any code I work with.

Comment: @N.Shead I suppose `auto createBubbles() -> Bubbles*(&)[arrayNumber]` could be an ok alternative though, or really just `auto& createBubbles()`.

Comment: Yes, `auto` type deduction is definitely the way to go there. Though honestly I'd prefer to not be returning array types at all — I just felt it worthwhile to point out the possibility!